# How to get inheritance to work for parameters inside a closure?

Tags: swift

```
protocol Proto {
  associatedtype Entity: NSManagedObject
}

extension Proto {
    func subscribe(completionBlock: @escaping (Entity) -> ())  {
       var helper = Helper()
       helper.subscribe(completionBlock)    //error out
    }
}

class Helper {
   func subscribe(completionBlock: @escaping (NSManagedObject) -> ()){}
}
```

Even though entity will always be of type NSManagedObject, but it won't let me pass that closure into another function that accepts NSmanagedObject. How to fix?

I can make the code work by doing this:

```
helper.subscribe(completionBlock as! (NSManagedObject) -> ())
```

But why do I need to force cast when Entity is of type NSManagedObject? Also are there any risk of it crashing at runtime if I cast like this? Is there ever a scenario if the cast will fail?

Comment: In the phrase `helper.subscribe`, what is `helper`?

Comment: instance of Helper....ok I'll make that more clear

Comment: Function types are contravariant, not covariant. Is that what you need to know? (Hard to tell, with all the extra protocol and extension kerfuffle clouding up the question.)

Comment: @matt So (Entity) -> () is not the same type as (NSManagedObject) -> () ? Even though Entity is NSManagedObject?

Comment: So is that the question after all? No, of course they are not “the same type”. But if it’s about overriding and substitution, it actually works the other way round: see for instance https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html

Comment: According to the article it should work, example given on that page: let returnsAnimal: () -> Animal = catF

Comment: That's why I'm still trying to elicit from you whether this is about protocols or about substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after some back and forth I believe the question amounts to this. Given this function:

```
func foo(v:UIView, f:(UIView)->Void) {
    f(v)
}
```

...why is it illegal to pass a `(UIButton)->Void` into `foo` as its `f` parameter?

Well, let's imagine that we *could* do that. (This is called a *reductio ad absurdum* proof.) Then we could write this:

```
let bar : ((UIButton)->Void) = {button in print(button.currentTitle)}
foo(v:UISwitch(), f:bar)
```

And what would happen? `foo` would pass a UISwitch into `f` - legally, because `f` is typed as taking a UIView, and a UISwitch is indeed a UIView. And we would crash, because a UIView has no `currentTitle` property.

Do you see the problem? Characterising a function as a `(UIButton)->Void` gives that function the right, in the eyes of the compiler, to talk to the parameter as if it were a UIButton. But on the outside, `f` is typed as a function that takes a UIView. So it is legal to pass *any* UIView into it. Therefore the compiler needs to know that the function being held by `f` does *not* think that its parameter is a UIButton, lest it do that very sort of thing.

So the compiler very rightly stops you right at the door and doesn't let you pass `bar` into `foo` in the first place. The rule is that function types are *contravariant* on their parameter types, for passing.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about case 6 and case 7. I would have thought that 6 is legal and 7 is illegal. Generally if a function asks for a parent lets say func f(_ uiview:UIView), you can definitely call f( UIButton() ) because UIButton IS a UIView. For some reason when it's a part of a function type, its reversed. Why?

Comment: OK totally rewrote my answer to focus on just that (6).